# When does ship Evasive Action end?

Tags: planet-mercenary

According to the book, when doing ship-to-ship combat, every player gets an action each round (acting as the AI of the ship), and the enemy ships get a number of actions equal to their AI rating, and the Dodge action is replaced by Evasive Action. My understanding is that Dodge is maintained until the player's next turn (or until the end of the next round if they don't take an action for whatever reason). Does Evasive Action similarly last until the invoking player's next turn or until the end of the round? The situation seemed a bit more fuzzy since it's increased defense for all of the players in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked Alan on the [Gallant Knight Games Discord channel](https://discordapp.com/channels/478389342646173716/), and got an answer:

> Round implies until the end of the series of actions
>   So I'd say until the current turn set is over.

....

> They are back at base def [on the next turn] until someone takes the evade action.

Answer (score 1):

As noted above, I believe that Evasive Action should act like Dodge, and the increased defense effectively lasts until the end of the next turn or until someone chooses to do Evasive Action again in hopes of getting a better defense with their action (possibly the same person as the original one invoking it).

Comment: In the absence of an official answer (although I did try invoking Alan), I'm going to accept this as the most likely answer.